# How to use Paypal from a desktop application?

Tags: paypal, desktop-application

Is it possible to collect billing information and send it to Paypal from a desktop application the same way a webpage normally would?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paypal uses the HTTP protocol to communicate. As long as you use that with your desktop application, it will work.

As you can see from this [Sample Code](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code) page, they are simply using apis to make HTTP Requests ([cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) for the php example) to the paypal servers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this comes in too late for you, but it might help others looking around for similar functionality. I had also been looking around for a way that could let me search through paypal transactions and give me exact numbers about sales and sold products. Then I found [PaySketch](http://www.paysketch.com), which I have been using for a while now, and it has become a part of my schedule to (re)organize marketing and sales efforts based on statistics that I get from the app. I would say that it is a must have for every vendor selling things using paypal

Answer (score 0):

You can also try developing an adobe AIR application. The application will be platform independant. You can read more [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track your Paypal account from desktop, you can try [Putler](http://www.appsmagnet.com/paypal/putler). It won't let you accept new payments on the desktop, but can show you insightful reports.